# Strict warning Error

Tags: panels

I am getting this error when I create a new wiki...does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

> Strict warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   PanelizerEntityDefault->hook_field_attach_submit() (line 1113

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug. However, there is a workaround for it.

In admin/config/content/panelizer make sure to mark "Panelize", "Allow Panel Choice", and "Provide Default Panel".

Here is a [link](https://drupal.org/node/1988250) to where i found the solution